# Can I create color struct that works on different endians?

Tags: c, struct, colors, endianness, unions

I am trying to create a union to store my color values channel by channel and 4-byte values at the same time. But I am having problems with the order of channels. Different endian machines give different values. Is there any way to create endian proof version of this struct or use different structs when different endians are better for this job? I want to use structs and unions for educational purposes. I am experimenting and want to learn what can and can't do with C structs.

```
typedef union u_color
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char   blue;
        unsigned char   green;
        unsigned char   red;
        unsigned char   alpha;
    };
    unsigned int    value;
}   t_color;
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like an x/y problem. Yes, you're right, the endian-ness makes a difference when you access the `value` field. You'd need to resort to macro hacks if you want to swap endian-ness when accessing that.

Comment: It's not really clear what "endian proof version of this struct" means. For one, you seem to be assuming that an `unsigned int` is 4 bytes, which may not always be the case.And you seem to be assuming some order of the bytes in the 32-bit value. This question is weird,.

Comment: @pmacfarlane: Re “It's not really clear what "endian proof version of this struct" means”: It means they want the `alpha` member to always correspond to bits 24-31 of `value`, `red` to correspond to 16-23, `green` to correspond to 8-15, and `blue` to correspond to 0-7.

Comment: If you are using Clang or GCC, you can use `#if __LITTLE_ENDIAN__` to test the endianness and select code that lists the members in one order or another. That is not portable to all C compilers. However, kludges like that should be avoided or carefully controlled.

Comment: How is the information transferred between machines of different endianness? If it's saved in files, you need to agree on what endianness that rules etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it only for getting and setting the `value` (or getting colours from the `value`) then (if you use recent gcc family compilers)

```
typedef union u_color
{
  #if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
    struct
    {
        uint8_t   blue;
        uint8_t   green;
        uint8_t   red;
        uint8_t   alpha;
    };
  #else
    struct
    {
        uint8_t   alpha;
        uint8_t   red;
        uint8_t   green;
        uint8_t   blue;
    };
  #endif
    uint32_t    value;
}   t_color;
```

But for the defining arrays which will represent real screen data structures you need to use one predefined struct layout.

```
int main(void)
{
    t_color x = {.blue = 0x11, .green = 0x22, .red = 0x33, .alpha = 0x44};
    printf("%"PRIx32"\n", x.value);
}
```

Will always print 0x11223344 despite the endianness.

Comment: _"Will always print 0x11223344 despite the endianness."_ - There's also mixed endianess to consider if you want to send your information back in time :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo then I will add an additional check for PDP11 :). The problem will be finding the gcc version supporting those predefined macros :)

Comment: The first computer I was admin on! Awww!! PDP-11/84 Love! Don't worry. The manuals are still around ... :-) ( I didn't actually know it used mixed endianess when I wrote the comment though - surprise to me)

Comment: @TedLyngmo People do not live so long!  I was learning C when I was a teenager using this computer (quite late VLSI version). It was in my father's work data centre and it was the only machine I was allowed to use (as they stopped using it and migrated to VAX). VT100 terminal.

Comment: VT100?! Bah! You were LUCKY! In my day we were happy if we had [VT52](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue7wM0QC5LE)s - If we were _really_ lucky, they were VT52+'ses.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Starting with  VT52 you had 1's and 0's.  My first keyboard had to use 'i's and 'O's.  [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_Lettera_22#Keyboard). ;-)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You had keyboards!? We had bootstrapping - if dad was in a good mood. :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I still have my name written on a [slate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slate_(writing)) yet also self taught square root on an abacus.  Ah the joys of experience technology changes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica .".. and you try telling the young people of today that ... and they won't believe you".

Comment: Supposedly we'll be able to do this in standard C soon, with C23 stdbit.h. `__STDC_ENDIAN_NATIVE__ == __STDC_ENDIAN_BIG__` etc. I don't think any compiler supports that yet though.

Answer (score 1):

Although one could re-order the color/alpha members based on endian, when reading and writing to a graphics file, the sequence of *red, green, blue* is the norm.  I recommend to stay with that.

Code can store 4 bytes at a time with a `struct` of r,g,b,a instead of an `unsigned`.

A pixel color is not a good example for `union/struct`.

Using `(u)intN_t` types is a better first step than using `unsigned` when experimenting with `union`s.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying and experimenting with structs and unions.  And can you explain why (u)intN_t is better than unsigned values?

Comment: Graphics file formats often have specified bit widths and so can be matched with `(u)intN_t`.  Further, certain graphics data manipulations are bit width specific.  `int, long, ...` have _minimum_ bit width requirements but actual width can vary from implementation to implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The KISS solution is simply to drop the union and the value member, then always obtain the value through a function instead. 100% portable:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t blue;
  uint8_t green;
  uint8_t red;
  uint8_t alpha;
} t_color;

uint32_t t_color_value (const t_color* col)
{
  return ( ((uint32_t)col->blue  << 24) |
           ((uint32_t)col->green << 16) |
           ((uint32_t)col->red   <<  8) |
           ((uint32_t)col->alpha <<  0) );
}

int main (void)
{
  t_color col = { .blue=0x11, .green=0x22, .red=0x33, .alpha=0x44};
}
```

Now `blue` will always end up in the `uint32_t` most significant byte, regardless of endianess. This is because the shift operators are endianess-independent (unlike a union or memcpy etc).

Comment: Thanks for the help but this question is not only about solving the issue. I am trying to learn how structs, unions, and preprocessors can be used and how much flexibility I have.

Comment: @BuğrahanÖzcan Part of that is to realize when they do the job poorly, namely when it comes to representing memory maps and data protocols. Endianess and alignment will often make code relying on struct/union non-portable.